# Setting up Tezos node and Calling APIs

Tags: tezos-client

1. Can any one please help with Apis to get the blocks, transactions and addresses after setting up the node

Comment: Do you have a more specific question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi arvidj, I want to set up tezos node and use the apis of tezos to fetch a particuar block info, particular address info and transactions

Comment: Have a look at the RPCs: http://tezos.gitlab.io/developer/rpc.html

Comment: arvidj i already looked into that could you help me find if you have used it or seen the apis for particular block, particular addressinfo and transactions

Comment: for a block: http://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#get-block-id

Comment: I had for the blockId but i need for the the transactions that the block has

Comment: Transactions are a type of operation included in the block. You can try the "GET ../<block_id>/operations" API : http://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-operations

Comment: Thanks arvidj. It helped

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [RPCs](http://tezos.gitlab.io/developer/rpc.html).
Transactions are a type of operation included in the block.
You can try the `GET ../<block_id>/operations` API. See [here](http://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-operations).

Comment: Thank you arvidj. It helps